# Excecute loop within a 'If...Then' statement VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am adding cells from multiple workbooks into a single workbook by specifying the cell in a formula and adding them to a designated cell/column in my new workbook. I would also like to include a for loop within my 'if.. then..With' statement. I would like my 'for' loop to add the the specified range A2:C57 from each of the sheets 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 into the cells G,H,I and so on. How can I add this loop in my current VBA code?

```
Sub GetData()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim SheetName As String
Dim n As Long
Dim NewRow As Long

MyPath = "C:\attach"
SheetName = "Title"


FileName = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xlsx")
Do While FileName <> ""
 If FileName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   NewRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  'Transferring cells from worksheet(2)"Title" into "Sheet1" in thisworkbook"
  With .Range("A" & NewRow)
    .Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!B4"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  With .Range("B" & NewRow)
    .Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!B5"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  With .Range("C" & NewRow)
    .Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!B6"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  With .Range("D" & NewRow)
    .Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!B7"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  With .Range("E" & NewRow)
    .Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!A1"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  With .Range("F" & NewRow)
    .Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!A2"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  'Selects the range A2:C57 from sheets 3,4,5,6,7,8,9
  With .Range("G" & NewRow)
   Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    k = 1   'row counter for destination sheet
    'loop sheets 3-9
     For i = 3 To 9
         'loop rows 2-57
          For j = 2 To 57
            'if C is not empty
                If WrkBookSrs.Sheets(i).Cells(j, 3).Value <> "" Then
                 'code here to add A:C on this row into this workbook in sheet1 column G.

                         k = k + 1'increment counter for next row
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation and pseudo code are not very clear.
Are you wanting to add the sums of all the values from the cells (A:C) in your loop?
Your comments mention just columns A:C being used

So if I understand correctly you should be able to set a variable to the sum of the values

```
With WrkBookSrs.Sheets(i)
   newGvalue= .Cells(j, 1).Value + .Cells(j, 2).Value + .Cells(j, 3).Value
End With
```

Comment: Not addition , just transferring the data. in columns A:C

Answer (score 0):

Add a for loop like this.

```
For q = 3 To 9
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & q)
```

If you are only wanting to include the same sheets over and over, this should work. Of course adjust the range of q to meet your specs